# Keep on clicking button 1 until button 2 appears in selenium using java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium-ios

I am testing a native iOS mobile app using selenium and appium with Java code. As part of my teardown, I have to keep  on clicking "back" button until "setting" button appears from where I can logout of the application.

I tried few things using do while but not working. Can anyone help please ?

Comment: code you tried will help to suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code may be help you

```
try {
        boolean flag = true;
        while(flag) {
            WebElement backBtn = driver.findElementByName("back");
            backBtn.click();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            boolean isFindSettingBtn = driver.findElementsByName("setting").size() !=0;
            if(isFindSettingBtn) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```